# How do I center and limit page content with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap5, I want to achieve (mostly) the same effect as:

```css
margin: 0 auto;
width:60%;
```

in CSS. The code above doesn't work in Bootstrap - it aligns items to the left of the page.
How do I limit the width to the middle 60% and then make content take up that 60% in 2 columns?

Edit: HTML code *(style.css only contains text-align and colors)*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="row">
            <div class="col-12" id="header_id"></div> <!--header_id is just for a background image-->
        </header>
        <section class="row">
                <article class="col-4">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates animi ratione esse, aut
                    vel iusto voluptas voluptatum illo suscipit veniam, laudantium qui, quidem nihil eaque repellendus
                    ducimus facilis velit sequi.</article>
                <article class="col-4">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates animi ratione esse, aut
                    vel iusto voluptas voluptatum illo suscipit veniam, laudantium qui, quidem nihil eaque repellendus
                    ducimus facilis velit sequi.</article>
                <article class="col-4">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates animi ratione esse, aut
                    vel iusto voluptas voluptatum illo suscipit veniam, laudantium qui, quidem nihil eaque repellendus
                    ducimus facilis velit sequi.</article>
                <article class="col-4">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates animi ratione esse, aut
                    vel iusto voluptas voluptatum illo suscipit veniam, laudantium qui, quidem nihil eaque repellendus
                    ducimus facilis velit sequi.</article>
                <article class="col-4">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates animi ratione esse, aut
                    vel iusto voluptas voluptatum illo suscipit veniam, laudantium qui, quidem nihil eaque repellendus
                    ducimus facilis velit sequi.</article>
        </section>
        <footer class="row">
            <div class="col-12 align-center static-bottom">LICENCE</div> <!-- align-center is just for aligning text -->
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML code to repro the issue

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you tried the auto class.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-auto mb-4 text-center">
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3 shadow-sm h-100 mx-auto" style="max-width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-header"><span class="reportTitle">Test</span></div>
      <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Look I'm Centered</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                      <div class="btn-group">
                          <a href="#"  type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" target="_blank">App</a>
                      </div> 
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```